# Creating a Dynamic Collage with Video and Images in React Native

Tags: react-native, npm, frontend, expo, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm trying to create a collage feature in React Native that enables users to create collages with videos and images, similar to Facebook's feature. Existing libraries like "react native fb collage" and "react native masonry" haven't provided the desired outcome. These libraries lack the seamless integration of videos and images as seen on Facebook.

I'm looking for a solution that offers responsive layouts, allowing users to freely position and resize elements. Gesture support for resizing and repositioning is crucial. If you've tackled a similar challenge or know of a suitable library, I'd greatly appreciate your insights, code snippets, or tutorials. Thank you!

[image: What I have achieved uptill now][image: What I want to exactly Acheive]